# No module named "encondings"

Tags: windows, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

When running my Python peoject everything is ok. After i compile my project in Windows with pyinstaller `pyinstaller __main__.spec`  there is a problem when running the .exe file.

> Py_initialize: unable to load the file system codec
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encondings'

Bellow is my **main**.spec

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
block_cipher = None

 a = Analysis(['__main__.py'],
         pathex=['C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\l_concept'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[],
         hiddenimports=['encodings'],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher)


      exclude_binaries=False,

      name='__main__',




      debug=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      console=True )
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      Tree('C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\l_concept\\providers', prefix='providers'),
      Tree('C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\l_concept\\utils', prefix='utils'),

      exclude_binaries=False,

      name='__main__',




      debug=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
           a.binaries,
           a.zipfiles,
           a.datas,
           strip=False,
           upx=True,
           name='__main__')
```

When i compile my program in linux everithing is ok, i already added the lin hiddenimports=['encondings'] to my .spec file but nothing was changed.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

can run cmd with administrator and write in cmd

`python namefile.py` can run correctly

you forget to select "Add Python (2.x)3.x to PATH" when install python.

can add path manually [add python to the windows path](https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path)